# YII CListView Ajax multiple TextField filter

Tags: ajax, yii

I have a CListView which I want to filter using Ajax. I have 2 textfields. Now they both filter the same column: titel. I'm searching quite some time now, but I can't seem to figger out why they both filter the titel and not the locatie too..

It's my first time to use Ajax so, i'm afraid I don't know exactly how to pass the right parameters at the moment and am kind of lost. Someone who can help me?

So here's my view:

```
<?php echo CHtml::beginForm(CHtml::normalizeUrl(array('kunstwerk/index')), 'get', array('id'=>'filter-form'))?>

<?php echo CHtml::textField('string', (isset($_GET['string'])) ? $_GET['string'] : '', array('id'=>'locatie'));?>

<?php echo CHtml::textField('string', (isset($_GET['string'])) ? $_GET['string'] : '', array('id'=>'titel'));?>
```

and..

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('search',
        "var ajaxUpdateTimeout;
        var ajaxRequest;

        $('input#titel').keyup(function(){
            titel = $(this).serialize();
            clearTimeout(ajaxUpdateTimeout);
            ajaxUpdateTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
                $.fn.yiiListView.update(
        // this is the id of the CListView
                    'ajaxListView',
                    {data: titel}
                )
            },
        // this is the delay
            300);
        });

        $('input#locatie').keyup(function(){
            locatie = $(this).serialize();
            clearTimeout(ajaxUpdateTimeout);
            ajaxUpdateTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
                $.fn.yiiListView.update(
        // this is the id of the CListView
                    'ajaxListView',
                    {data: locatie}
                )
            },
        // this is the delay
            300);
        });"
    );
```

and..

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
        'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
        'itemView'=>'_view',
        'sortableAttributes'=>array(
            'titel'
        ),
        'id'=>'ajaxListView',
    )); 
?>
```

Here's my controller:

```
public function actionIndex($string = '')
    {
        $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
        if( strlen( $string ) > 0 )
            $criteria->addSearchCondition( 'titel', $string, true, 'OR' );
            $criteria->addSearchCondition( 'locatie', $string, true, 'OR' );

        $dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider( 'Kunstwerk', array( 'criteria' => $criteria, ) );

        //$dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Kunstwerk');
        $this->render('index',array(
            'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
            'bedrijven' => Bedrijf::model()->findAll(),
        ));
    }
```

Comment: Does ajax request goes to actionindex?

Comment: well, I think it should be, but on the other hand I think it doesn't. The filter is on the index page. But if I remove criteria on the action index it still works the same way. But I have no idea where he gets is information from to filter the 'titel' field at the moment...

Comment: Found out that he always compares the first varchar column from my database table, which is 'titel'. Does someone know how I can compare another column?

Comment: ok, kindly add this line to your code CVarDumper::Dump($criteria,100,true);die(); after you set searchCondition. and see exactly what sql query is being executed.

Comment: thanks, I added your line, which works when I refresh/postback the page. When the ajaxrequest is fired it doesn't run actionIndex or the search function in my model. So I'm really puzzled and don't have any clue where it sets its sql command. So it fires and gives result but I cannot control the right database column..

Comment: btw, your line returns null when I do the ajax keyup request..

Comment: Solved... It didn't use it's actionIndex because I had a dataprovider in my view which overrided the actionIndex dataprovider. This is where het got it's query from. Was not in de code above, so no wonder you guys couldn't tell... So use your controller :p Thanks anyway Rafay!

Comment: Glad you have solved the problem.